# Sitecore Broken Links report

Tags: sitecore-client, sitecore-api, broken-links

Needs to get all the broken links for clean up purpose. Please let us know do we have any custom code to get all the broken links without power shell script. When we try get all broken links Sitecore Dashboard getting some memory issue[image].

We are using Sitecore 9.0.1 and deployed in AZURE.

Please help us here.

Answer (score 1):

When you click the "scan the database for broken links" link in the control panel, it opens "/sitecore/shell/applications/tools/broken-links" in a modal.

Looking in the file system in that location, you can see "Broken Links.xml". Within that file, you can see the code that is called is:

> Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Tools.BrokenLinks.BrokenLinksForm,Sitecore.Client"

Using DotPeek or some other tool, you can then see the code that is called within that assembly. The code that you are looking for specifically is:

```
Database database = Factory.GetDatabase(databaseName);
ItemLink[] brokenLinks = Globals.LinkDatabase.GetBrokenLinks(database);
itemLinkList = BrokenLinksForm.Scanner.GetFilteredItemLinks(database, (IReadOnlyCollection<ItemLink>) brokenLinks, excludeSystemItems, showLatestVersion);
```

You could use this as a starting point to get the links yourself via some custom code.

However... I fear if the OTB sitecore tools are hitting memory exceptions, then  anything you write yourself will have the same difficulties.

You could try going to the tool directly:

> <local.ca>/sitecore/shell/applications/tools/broken-links

Or try the Remove Broken Links Tool in the admin area:

> <local.ca>/sitecore/admin/RemoveBrokenLinks.aspx

But ultimately, you really need to address your memory issue.  Could you not upscale the instance for a short period to perform the maintenance?

One final point, remember in order for the broken links report to be accurate, you need to first rebuild the links database.